# How to efficiently compute gradients layer-wise in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I am trying to implement the distributed synchronous SGD approach described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00981) using Tensorflow. For that I need to compute and apply gradients layer-wise. In principle I can do it in the following way (obs! incomplete code:

```
#WORKER CODE
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
for layer_vars in all_layer_vars:
    grads_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss, layer_vars)
    grads = sess.run([grad_var[0] for grad_var in grads_vars], feed_dict)
    send_grads_to_master(zip(grads, layer_vars))

#MASTER CODE
while (True):
    grads_vars = receive_grads_from_worker()
    sess.run(opt.apply_gradients(grads_vars))
```

What I wonder is whether in this scenario (with several `compute_gradients()` calls, within different `session.run()'s`) the number of internal operations performed by Tensorflow is the same or higher than in the "standard" scenario where all grads are computed with just one invocation of `compute_gradients()`.

That is, thinking on the backpropagation algorithm, I wonder if in this distributed scenario Tensorflow will compute the different "`delta's`" only once, or not. If the latter, is there a more efficient way of doing what I want?

Comment: It might help to explain why you are applying layer-wise gradients.  From your code above it will be more efficient to write your graph so the session only needs to run once and both computes and applies all the gradients by layer but only needs to execute the graph once.   [Here](https://github.com/beopst/dcn.tf/blob/master/train.py#L80) is an example of layer-wise gradients in practice being done with one graph execution.

Comment: Thanks @user728291. I have updated the question, so that it is hopefully more clear what I want to do and why. As you can see, I cannot perform the computation and application of gradients with one session run.